# Conditions for the existence of a solution to a semilinear second-order PDE with a-priori bounds

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

Consider the general semilinear elliptic second-order PDE
$$
u_t-\mathcal L u=f\left(t,x,u,\nabla u\right)
$$
where $\mathcal L$ is an elliptic linear operator (like minus the Laplace operator), $t \in [0,T],$ $x$ is in a bounded smooth domain $\Omega,$ and the boundary conditions are
$$
u(T,x)=c, \quad \forall x\in\Omega
$$
where $c$ is a constant. $f$ can be nonlinear in $u$ and $\nabla u$ with at most quadratic growth in both of them, and has no singularity in both of them and $x$. For example,
$$
f\left(t,x,u,\nabla u\right) = x^\alpha u^2 + ∇u \cdot ∇u
$$
is a possible form. Mind that this is a Cauchy problem with final data, a situation which fits with the "backward" heat operator $\partial_t+\Delta$.

Suppose we know from the original problem that the solution to this PDE is bounded by two smooth $\mathcal C^2(\Omega)$ functions: $$\underline u \leq u \leq \overline u, \quad \forall (t,x)\in[0,T]\times \Omega.$$ My question is: is there a result (with possible conditions on $f$) to provide an existence result for a (weak) solution to this PDE ? any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check your "boundary condition" on $\nabla u$.

Comment: Hi Giorgio, thanks for the comment, I edited the question.

Comment: Do you really want that the full gradient vanishes on the boundary?

Comment: absolutely not, I'm free for anything that can help for proving existence. The domain of $x$ is originally unbounded in my case, but the problems does not make sense for extreme values, and any condition at the boundaries could be added to ensure existence.

Comment: I have some comments. First of all, I think you are just interested in global existence, since for small times locally Lipschitz suffices. If we use Holder spaces,  global existence holds if $u$ and $\nabla u$ do not blow up in the sup-norm. I know similar computations in the elliptic case where one needs $C^{3, \alpha}$ spaces and the same could hold in the parabolic case. One needs assumptions on $f$ preventing the above blow-up. I would consult Chapter 7 of the book of Friedman: PDE of parabolic type (and later Ladyzhenskaya-Solonnikov-Uralceva)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am indeed interested in global existence. Global existence of a solution in a weak sense is also enough for me if I find some appropriate space. Regarding Hölder spaces, provided I somehow show $\nabla u$ does not blow up, is there a theorem that can be used directly to show existence ? Also, in my case I do not have a parabolic PDE, can I use the results for parabolic equations in my case ?

Comment: I have another question: can you please point to a reference with the result on local existence being a result of $f$ being locally lipschitz ?

Comment: Have a look at Section 4, Chapter 7 of the book of Friedmann. Theorem 10 deals with small time existence. Concerning global existence when there is no blow up in the sup norm, the basic idea is explained before theorem 8. From boundedness in the sup norm, one deduces boundeness in the Holder norm to apply a fix point theorem. It is far from being immediate.

Comment: Thank you for the references, I will read the Chapter 7 of the book, as it looks like what I need. I understand that all is easier if a-priori bounds are found for $\nabla u.$ I would be greateful if you think of a paper or something else where this has been applied to prove existence of a semilinear pde, as simple examples can sometimes be insightful.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look  also at Krylov: lectures on elliptic and parabolic equations in Holder spaces. See exercise 4.3.9 in the elliptic case. See also 8.9.5 where however the growth is subquadratic

Comment: Hi Giorgio. First thank you again for the references. After some research, I came across the Nagumo type existence results for second-order elliptic pdes. Basically it states that if one can find sub and super-solutions and a-priori bounds on the solution, then the Nagumo condition on the nonlinear part of the PDE is enough to ensure existence. What are your thoughts on that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of reading, I came across the (enlightening) paper:
**On principally linear elliptic differential equations of the second order, Nagumo 1954**.
Basically, the (classical) results there shows that for any bounded domain $\Omega$ for your space variables, if you have lower and upper solutions for a quasi-linear / semi-linear PDE, and that your nonlinear operator in the PDE has at most quadratic growth in the gradient, then you can have (in this order) bounds on the solution and on the gradient in your bounded domain. I recommend reading it for simple scalar PDEs.
That being said, I did not need to find upper and lower solutions since I already had nice smooth à-priori bounds for my PDE. But for some simple PDEs, finding upper and lower solutions can be easy by trying constants, or simple form functions.
I wanted to leave this here in case someone with à-priori knowledge on the solution of their quasi-linear or semi-linear PDE and less than quadratic growth in their nonlinearity wanted some simple applicable result to prove existence, without having to go through all the weak-solution theory, which I think could take a few months to master.